# Footer appears in the wrong position

Tags: html, css, footer

my footer appears on the bottom of my screen when I load my page, but I would like it to be a sticky footer, I tried following this tutorial, but it didn't work and this was the result. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

The tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/  (I'm using the second method)

```css
body {
  background-color: #5995ED;
}

.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
.Logo img {height: 50px; }
.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class=content>
  <nav>
    <a class=Logo href=index.html><img src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/17/06/c6/1706c603-2e3a-4fe0-7e00-7794c85eb200/source/256x256bb.jpg"></a>
    <div>
      <h1 class=texthead>Consonare</h1>
      <i>Evangelické pozounové sbory</i>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <a class=link1 href=Galerie.html>Galerie</a>
  <a class=link2 href=Kontaky.html>Kontakty</a>
  <a class=link3 href=sbory.html>Sbory</a>
  <a class=link4 href=Budouciakce.html>Budoucí akce</a>
  <a class=link5 href=dokumenty.html>Dokumenty</a>

  <h1>Sbory</h1>
  <div style="position:absolute; top:175; left:25;">
    <h3>Olomouc</h3>
    <p>Farní sbor Českobratrské církve evangelické<br> Blahoslavova 1, 772 00 Olomouc</p>
    zkoušky: v neděli po bohoslužbách<br> kontakt: Stanislav Jílek<br> tel: 730 167 113; email: Jilek.S@seznam.cz<br> web: <a href=https://consonare.evangnet.cz/olomouc>consonare.evangnet.cz/olomouc</a>
    <br>
    <h3>České Budějovice</h3>
    Tř. 28 října 28, České Budějovice; zkoušky: úterý 17 hod.<br> kontakt: Josef Hejzlar<br> tel: 775 914 044, e-mail: Josef.Hejzlar@seznam.cz<br>
    <h3>Chomutov</h3>
    ul. 28 řijna 1071/12, fara Chomutov<br> zkoušky: jak kdy večer<br> kontakt: Štěpán Bílek<br> email: StepanBilek@seznam.cz<br>
    <h3>Jablonec nad Nisou</h3>
    Pod Baštou 10, fara Jablonec; zkoušky: společné v Rumburku<br> kontakt: Klára Pavlíková<br> tel: 777 315 719; e-mail: pavlikova.klara@gmail.com<br>
    <h3>Praha</h3>
    Kostel CČE Vinohrady, Korunní 1440/60, Praha 2; zkoušky: úterý 19:30 hod.<br> kontakt: Vojtěch Rozsíval, tel: 608 873 420; e-mail: v.rozs@email.cz
    <h3>Rumburk - Varnsdorf</h3>
    Krásnolipská 540/22, fara Rumburk; zkoušky: pátek 20:30 hod.<br> kontakt: Evžen <br> tel: 720 618 205, e-mail: evzen.s@centrum.cz<br>
    <h3>Třebenice</h3>
    Tyršova 505, fara Třebenice; zkoušky: neděle po bohoslužbách<br> kontakt: Jan Zalabák<br> tel: 603 196 154; e-mail: jan.zalabak@trebenice.cz<br>
    <h3>Vrchlabí</h3>
    Českých bratří 112, fara Vrchlabí; zkoušky: čtvrtky 18:15-19:45<br> kontakt: Petr Chlápek<br> tel: 604 282 497; e-mail: vrchlabi@evangnet.cz<br>
    <h3>Boskovice</h3>
    zkoušky: Hybešova 8, Boskovice, pondělí 17:00<br> kontakt: Jiří Bureš<br> email: jiri.bures@evangnet.cz<br>
    <h3>Nosislav</h3>
    fara, Masarykova 156, Nosislav<br> zkoušky: lichý pátek v 19 hodin.<br> kontakt: Vladimír Lukl<br> tel: 721 866 861, e-mail: vladimir.lukl@post.cz<br>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  Footer
</footer>
```

[image: what appears on my screen]

Comment: I made you a snippet. That does not look like the picture. I added a height to the image I found

Comment: What? I need to fix the footer not the image the image was fine.

Comment: I just let you know that to use an external image in the snippet I made YOU, I had to resize the image. I did not post a SOLUTION, just made your question easier to ANSWER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one  it should work now

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Sbory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <style>
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
}
.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
}


  </style>
  
  </head>
  
  <body bgcolor=5995ED>

<div class="content">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer 
</footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: At first this did not  work than I realized that problem all along was that I had a div with absolute position. I needed this for the effect of getting the items under Sbory to be shifted to the right.

Comment: yes exactly you were giving absolute position to a div that was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change you footer css to this

```
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: nice but that is not a sticky footer

Comment: the sticky means that it stays at the bottom of the page at all times not at the bottom of the screen

Comment: for example on this webpage there is a sticky footer (is black and starts with STACK OVERFLOW)